# How to invert transform an area to the original space given a transformation matrix in Python

Tags: python-3.x, linear-algebra, coordinate-transformation

Starting with a geometric structure in a 3D real space I have transformed the space to a new space S using a transformation matrix A.  In that transformed space S I have generated new structures and calculated their surfaces.

I want now to revert to the original (real) space.  How can I convert a number referring to face areas in the transformed space S to the original real Space?

The matrix A --getting me from the real space to the new space S-- is the following:

```
A = np.array([[ 1.02218371e+01, -5.01184000e-03,  8.28603000e-03],
       [ 5.15849000e-03,  1.02218013e+01,  4.49135000e-03],
       [-8.39027000e-03, -4.58925000e-03,  1.02220817e+01]])
```

The surfaces I must translate back to the original real space are the following:

```
surfaces = np.array([8.15231027e-02, 3.30759780e-01, 1.30762826e-01, 1.23423172e-01,
        2.53063255e-03, 2.07243636e-01, 5.72893176e-02, 1.27633931e-01,
        4.67597873e-01, 2.18306734e-01, 5.21108558e-02, 2.46893051e-04,
        1.17762718e-01, 2.87337420e-01, 2.53063255e-03, 4.64298934e-04,
        8.37463483e-03])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you apply a transformation matrix `A` to a set of coordinates, you can get back the original by applying the [*inverse transformation*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152462/inverse-of-transformation-matrix) to the transformed coordinates. Compute the inverse of `A` using [`numpy.linalg.inv()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.inv.html)

```
c_transformed = A * c_original
A_inv = np.linalg.inv(A)
c_original2 = A_inv * c_transformed
```

Mathematically, you have

```
A_inv * c_transformed = A^-1 * A * c_original = I * c_original = c_original
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to go back and get the area that you would have in the original space. Depending on their orientations, surfaces are not affected in the same way bu the transformation. Think about shrinking the space vertically. The area of something in the horizontal plane stays unchanged while the area of let's say a door is shrinked. This means that you can't go back if the surface area is the only information you have